# CreateQuery is not valid without active transaction Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Hello i am stuck with the following problem ,When i am using `sessionFactory.openSession();` it working properly but Session session = `this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();` i am getting following error

**DAO**

```
public List<Bank> listbank(String bankId) {

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Bank ");
        List<Bank>bankList =query.list();
        session.close();
        return bankList;
    }
```

**error**

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at
```

My application is running with spring and hibernate with Jersey

**Databaseconfig.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>classpath:properties/database.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" >
             <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/> 



</beans>
```

ApplicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd"


    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    >   

    <!-- for database configuration -->
    <import resource="classpath*:/config/db-configuration.xml" />

    <!-- for spring-security-with-oauth configuration -->
    <import resource="classpath*:/config/spring-security-oauth2.xml" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>



</beans>
```

Comment: Remove `hibernate.current_session_context_class` from your configuration and make sure you have `@Transactional` on the method you are running.

Comment: @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS,readOnly=true)  is on Service layer

Comment: @M.Deinum removed `hibernate.current_session_context_class`   , now i am geting  `org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread`

Comment: which means you don't have `@Transactional` on your method.

Comment: @M.Deinum i done both now flowing error     'org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread'

Comment: Then you have multiple instances of your dao... You probably have both a contextloaderlistener and dispatcherservlet with a component-scan element?

Comment: @M.Deinum i was updated question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26842223/3381825 Check it out, may help

Answer (score 0):

you missed  session.beginTransaction(); in ur code.
place it after    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();